# Is it possible to avoid N+1 requests in this case?

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have the following class model:

[image]

I implemented it this way:

Project:

```
@Data
public class Project {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @ManyToMany
  @JsonIgnore
  @JoinTable(
          name = "employee_projects",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
  )
  private List<Employee> employees;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<Role> roles;

  // more fields
}
```

Employee:

```
@Data
public class Employee {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @ManyToMany
  @JsonIgnore
  @JoinTable(
          name = "employee_projects",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id")
  )
  private List<Project> projects;

  @ManyToMany
  @JsonIgnore
  @JoinTable(
          name = "employee_roles",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
  )
  private List<Role> roles;

  // more fields
}
```

Role:

```
public class Role {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JsonIgnore
  @NotNull
  private Project project;

  @ManyToMany
  @JsonIgnore
  @JoinTable(
          name = "employee_roles",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
  private List<Employee> employees;

  // more fields
  )
}
```

So each project has multiple employees and roles. In my application, im able to add an employee with a role to the project. So they are always a pair. An employee in a project always has one role. I control that in the businesslogic.

**Question:** Given a project, is it possible to find all its employees, connect each employee to his role in that project(thats the one role which is both connected to the employee and the given project, i make sure that theres only always one role which fullfills this condition) in one request?

So the call `findEmployeeWithRole(project)` should return a list of this class which contains all employees of the project with their associated role for this project:

```
public class EmployeeAndRole {

  private Employee employee;
  private Role role;
}
```

Im currently only able to achieve this in n+1 requests:

One request to find all the employees of the project:

```
@Query("SELECT project.employees FROM Project project WHERE project.id = :id")
List<Employee> findByProjectId(@Param("id") long id)
```

And then n requests(for each employee in the list) to find the role the employee is connected to in this project:

```
@Query("SELECT role FROM Role role WHERE role.project.id = :projectId AND :employeeId IN (SELECT employees.id FROM role.employees employees)
Role findByProjectIdAndEmployeeId(@Param("projectId") long projectId, @Param("employeeId") long employeeId)
```

Can i achieve this in one request? If not, what are my other options, should i try to remodel my class diagram?

Comment: why you execute a query instead of call getEmployes() on your project java bean?

Comment: I do, don´t know why i wrote a query here. But its the same thing anyways, because the employees are laziliy loaded.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to fix your mapping. One side of a bidirectional association must be the inverse side. Read https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand this correctly and if you search more a hibernate solution or a SQL solution but I think this would work :

```
SELECT
    p.employees

FROM project p

INNER JOIN employee e
    ON e.project.id = p.id      -- this ensure to get all emps from the selected project

LEFT JOIN role r                -- left join ensure to keep all records from employee, even if he hasn't a role
    ON  r.project.id = p.id     -- this ensure to get all role from the selected project
    AND r.employee.id = e.id    -- and linked to a employee too

WHERE
    p.id = :id
```

This is based on your "question" sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done in a single query. Your query will look something like this -

```
@Query(value = "select employee, role " +
            "from Employee as employee " +
            "inner join Project as project on employee member of project.employees " +
            "inner join Role as role on project = role.project and employee member of role.employees " +
            "where " +
            "  project.id = :projectId")
List<Tuple> getEmployeeRoles(Long projectId);
```

You can return a prettier list `List<EmployeeAndRole>` using the clas constructor in the jpa query.

Cheers!